# What is happening in the white space on dask distributed task stream dashboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

Below is the task stream dashboard. What is happening in the whitespace? Is that when my local python instance / dask scheduler is working? Is it when GC or another process is happening?

[image]

I want to find out what is happening during this period so I can reduce the whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the white space means that the workers are idle during those seconds. Whereas worker-blocking activity, communication and deserialisation, will show up as transparent blocks of red and grey, respectively, blank space means that the workers are not being given anything to work.

The main reason that this might happen, is that you are submitting a large graph, containing very many tasks, to the scheduler. The communication of this graph between the client and the scheduler can take time, and many processes within the scheduler for deciding where to allot work take some time too. The former is the more likely, and you would do well to consider if there is anything that you can do to reduce the size of the graph (e.g., bigger chunk sizes).

It is possible to profile what is taking time on the scheduler, although this is not generally exposed to users. You can profile activity within the client using regular python profiling tools.