# Why do I have such large gaps in my dask distributed task stream?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I've seen [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780656/how-to-reduce-white-space-in-the-task-stream), as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581461/what-is-happening-in-the-white-space-on-dask-distributed-task-stream-dashboard). The first says that the whitespace is from it being blocked by local work, but stepping through my program, the ~20 delay occurs right when I call dask.compute() and not in the surrounding code. The question asked said their issue was resolved by disabling garbage collection, but this did nothing for me. The second says to check the scheduler profiler, but that doesn't seem to be taking a long time either.

My task graph is dead simple - I'm calling a function on 500 objects with no task dependencies. (And repeat this 3 times, I'll link the functions once I figure out this issue). Here is [my dask performance report html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DF_B2WB3Sv-9nYzO-WTHGgCBgUa-M45C/view?usp=sharing), and [here is the section of code](https://github.com/scottshambaugh/monaco/blob/6f762a1af763dc2daf6e1a8b9cafcba9910195db/src/monaco/mc_sim.py#L570) that is calling dask.compute().

Any suggestions as to what could be causing this? Any suggestions as to how I can better profile to figure this out?

[image]

Comment: I have opened a github issue with a minimum working example here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/7066

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be the main problem, but lines 585/587 will result in transfer of computations to the local machine, this could slow-down/introduce a bottleneck in the computations. If the results are not used locally downstream, then one option is to leave computations on the remote machines calling `client.compute` (assuming the client is named as `client`):

```py
# changing 587: preprocessedcases = dask.compute(*preprocessedcases)
preprocessedcases = client.compute(*preprocessedcases)
```

Comment: Thanks! Right now I'm just testing stuff out locally so I don't think this should be affecting anything, but will make sure to switch it over in my next step.